# Laravel next/previous query with conditions and loop arounds

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

On my site, users can upload images. Images have their own pages.

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
$image = Images::where('url_title', $URLtitle)->where('created_by', $user->id)->first();
```

On these pages, I want a previous/next button that goes to the user's next/previous image. However, I want these to loop around as well.

For example, let's say a user has uploaded 3 images. Images with IDs 33, 55, and 61.

If you were on image 55, the previous image would be 33, and the next image would be 61.

However, if you were on image 61, the next image would loop around to 33.

How could I create a query that would allow me to create these links?

Comment: Why are you not doing this in javascript?

Comment: with your code that you are using right now, you only get the image with ID = 33?

Comment: @JamesRiady no, it's just an example.

Comment: If you want to get data collection, you have to use get(). and then you loop it in your view.. If you use first(), it will get only the first data of your collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind running some extra queries you could do:

```
$query = Images::where('url_title', $URLtitle)->where('created_by', $user->id);
$image = $query->first();
$prevImage = $query->where('id', '<', $image->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
$nextImage = $query->where('id', '>', $image->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
```

That should give you the nearest images on each side of your selected image.

Comment: $image returns the correct image, however $prevImage and $nextImage return null.

Comment: Well, your answers works when I rephrase it like so:

$prevImage = Images::where('created_by', $userID)->where('id', '<', $image->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();